# CQRS intent command event

Tags: architecture, cqrs

I am creating a web CRUD application that, after processing internal logic, will publish events to other systems in order to update their data.

I am in the first step of implementing CQRS and it sounds weird that I have to create specific commands for all possible intentions of the user in a Form where I only have one 'save' button. That means a lot of commands (for each property or value object) to capture an intention **not needed in my requirements** but needed in the upcoming projects that will subscribe to it. I am a fan of doing ONLY what my bounded context requires.

Another thing to take into account:
I have to use session to compare whether the data has changed or not. Faking the data after saving it will hide concurrency situations showing wrong data in the UI.

**EDIT:** I just found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883107/cqrs-and-crud-screens/2638849#2638849) where Greg Young suggests that some screens are just CRUD and there's nothing bad in making the update as default behavior.

Answer (score 6):

**Why do you want to use CQRS?** It does not work well for all cases.

Specifically, if you are using CRUD, then there might be no reason in trying CQRS at all. It just will not fit well. CQRS benefits a lot from the design, when user's intent is captured explicitly at the UI side and passed down to the server in meaningful command (that's not *FieldNameUpdated*, but rather CustomerRelocatedToNewAddress or CustomerAddressCorrected). This requires usage of Domain-Driven Design methodologies in the design).

Comment: I am doing it in that way.
My CRUD project is an internal 'configuration tool' to show the correct data in a high-traffic website, so I need to publish events. My perfect solution would be to achieve this project with just DDD, no CQRS, and publish an event for each real intention in my scope. The website should be achieved using CQRS since it will have thousands of users. I don't see why I have to create so many commands when my requirements just says 'create a form with a save button'

Comment: If the only reason for CQRS is scalability, then you can just try something simpler. I.e.: using some sort of memory cache to reduce the load on web sites (or publish web views in a way that don't stress the DB - i.e.: JSON on CDN), or just tweak the default server caching. CQRS usually comes in, when project needs to deal with a few of these: handle complex business scenario, scale, have rich BI capabilities, adapt to rapidly changing requirements.

Comment: the scenario is complex and systems are running already with memcache. We can get a lot of benefits from CQRS-practices, there's no doubt about this decision, the website will be rebuilt with CQRS. The doubt refers mainly to those small projects sorrounding the website and if they should send a big command or small commands instead (the same about events). All this thoughts come from a developer with strong background of DDD, bounded contexts and delivering succesfuly. Now I have to code all the intents and deal with session to keep the version of the data. (BTW I love reading your blog)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to clarify the case! Then, indeed, it looks like a single command might be a better (and simpler choice in this situation). At least, since the projects are small, should you encounter the need to refine the domain, it will not be a big problem to replace an UpdateCommand with more granular entities.