# CQRS and Conflicts Upon Submitting Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cqrs, event-sourcing

So I recently started reading about CQRS/Event Sourcing and it seems really interesting.  However, I just can't wrap my head around a situation that this seems to lend itself to.

Say we have this controller action:

```
public ActionResult UpdateCustomerName(int customerId, string newName) {
    var aggregateRoot = _customerQueryService.GetCustomer(customerId);
    _bus.Send(new UpdateCustomerNameCommand{Customer = aggregateRoot, NewName = newName});

    return View();
}
```

That's code I've seen in some examples.  Detecting a conflict in the command handler is straightforward enough, so is trying some auto-merging.  What I don't see, and am confused about, is how this controller gracefully informs the user if & when a conflict occurs and cannot be resolved, resulting in the UpdateCustomerNameCommand being rejected.

Don't we need to inform the user somehow?

Comment: could you clarify what you are trying to do? Basically you have to define some agreement how it will be commited. And in case any commit do not meet requirements you should show an error, because of possible data inconsistency. One of approaches - First Commit. So 2 users try to commit. Both should check if data wasn't changed while editing. In case data changed - error

Comment: This issue isn't specific to CQRS, it's present in every system with concurrent users. Either you use pessimistic concurrency and try to lock records (doesn't scale) or use optimistic concurrency and warn the users when conflicts occur

Comment: As a side note, I believe the controller should not be retrieving the aggregate (creating a dependency). The command should simply take it's id and expected version, as retrieved from the read-model when the "UpdateCustomerNameView" was created .

Answer (score 4):

The typical solution to detecting a conflict is to work with an "expected version" of the event stream in the command you are submitting.

In the client form, when querying for the information to display, you ensure that you also get the current version of the aggregate root or event stream. This version is then set as the expected version when submitting a command.

The command handling logic then can detect the conflict if the expected version does not match the current event stream version. Depending on the command, and your desired behavior, several things can be attempted:

1. If the new command does not conflict with anything (e.g. adding an order line), you can simply execute it.
2. You can try to merge its effects with changes that were made since the expected version using custom logic.
3. You can emit an event specific to the conflict, that may enable the user to  resolve it.
4. You can fail the command.

There is no general recipe here. It really depends on what the conflict semantically means and how a user would like to resolve such conflicts. If (parts) of the conflict can be automatically resolved, do so, and leave the rest to be resolved by the user.

Note that situations like these are not errors. They are to be expected if you want to allow users to concurrently work on things and you **and your users** know that you are working in an *eventually consistent* world.

**Update after question edit:**
The new example you gave is a bit contrived because it does not reveal the intent for this change, nor how it is relevant to any business rules or processes, but I will run with it using a context in which intent is very relevant by adapting it a bit. Let us suppose this software is used in an organization that is responsible for processing [legal name changes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_change).

So we might have the following intention revealing commands available to the clerks processing granted name change requests resulting from court orders, marriage or divorce:

```
ChangeLegalNameToMarriedName(... command specific info ...);
ChangeLegalNameToDivorcedName(... command specific info ...);
ChangeLegalNameToNaturalizedName(... command specific info ...);
ChangeLegalNameToNewGenderName(... command specific info ...);
... others
```

It is likely that each of these commands would invoke some different business logic while processing the command, e.g. ensuring that the person's status is 'married' when a `ChangeLegalNameToDivorcedName` command is received.

Additionaly it is likely to kick of other processes that need to occur after the change has been made. I.e. the `LegalNameChangedToNaturalizedName` event that is generated after the change was made may kick off a business process that sends an email to the associated immigration officer. The `LegalNameChangedToDivorcedName` event may kick off a process that notifies all local dating agencies about a potential new customer ;-).

So following your example, suppose that Clerk 1 just submitted a `ChangeLegalNameToNewGenderName` command with an expected aggregate version of 5, and we consider two different potentially conflicting situations:

1. **Clerk 2 processed the same request in the mean time and sent the same command.** 
   Because commands on an aggregate are generally processed transactionally, suppose Clerk 2's command was processed first, succeeds and bumps the aggregate version to 6. When Clerk 1's command gets handled, we detect a potential conflict. By inspecting the events generated since version 5, we can see that the `LegalNameChangedToNewGenderName` is present, and its content matches with the command submitted by Clerk 1. Thus according to our business rules we do the following: (1) skip executing Clerk 1's request (2) execute the `RegisterDuplicateNameChangeRequestProcessingAttempt` command on the `LegalNameChangeProcess` aggregate, which in turn may generate an event for a supervisor to check what is going wrong with the internal process.
2. **In the mean time, a legal name change command with a different content was processed.** This would represent an exceptional and potentially alarming situation for the organization. It should lead to action to resolve (a) a potentially broken internal process (b) a potentially fraudulent legal name change attempt. What might be done is (1) revert the person's name caused by the first command using a compensating command, marking it as requiring resolution. (2) Executing the `ResolvePotentiallyFraudulentLegalNameChange` command on the `LegalNameChangeProcess` aggregate.

If, as may be the case for the example you provided, there is no valuable business logic associated with e.g. a customer name, don't use CQRS for (that part of) your application, but simply do CRUD. Only use it where it adds real value. See e.g. the discussion here [CQRS and CRUD screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883107/cqrs-and-crud-screens/2638849).

Also note that it is possible for the UI/client to receive generated events, so that the user can be notified about the fact that a name change occurred while editing. Obviously this only reduces the likelihood of a race, it does not prevent it. If in your example the occurrence of a race means that the "name change" command should not be performed, you can generate a "name change rejected" event, that can be delivered back to the user (using e.g. correlation id's on the command & event).

Comment: I agree with @Alex. This is good plan for handling such situations. Merge or fail or handle in custom way. If there are strong requirements for concurrent work you should develope some sort of transaction logic that will lock entities that are edited at the moment and notify other users about this (in real time manner for example).

Comment: Yes, CQRS does not *solve* all conflicts automatically.  But, it does allow logic when a conflict occurs.  For example, one user could have a *more important* role and their command could always win.

Comment: ....generate a "name change rejected" event.... Question: That the command was rejected is not related to a state change so should that really be an event?